# SQL compilation error when casting a column named "file"

Tags: casting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When casting a column named `file`, Snowflake returns a strange error. The error does not happen without the type casting.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (file VARCHAR);
Table MY_TABLE successfully created.

SELECT file FROM my_table;
0 Row(s) produced.

SELECT file::VARCHAR FROM my_table;
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error: parse error line 1 at position 12 near '58'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty simple solution - quote the column identifier:

```
SELECT "FILE"::VARCHAR FROM my_table;
```

However, it's probably better to simply avoid using `file` as a column name, and go with something like `file_name` or `file_path` instead.

That error message could definitely be improved though!

And it seems like `file` should probably be a [reserved keyword](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/reserved-keywords.html) (isn't the case as of 2020-02-24).

Comment: Maybe the Snowflake SQL parser confuses the column name with the `FILE FORMAT` type of objects.  The `FILE` keyword is part of the `ALTER|CREATE|DROP|DESCRIBE|SHOW FILE FORMAT%` commands